# Peut-on utiliser les termes "nonante" et "septante" dans la documentation officielle en Belgique ?

Tags: nombres, belgique

Est-ce que les termes "nonante" et "septante" sont reconnus comme officiels en Belgique ? Certaines personnes me disent que c'est un dialecte, et du coup je me demandais si on pouvait les utiliser dans les documents officiels du pays.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Les mots "septante" et "nonante" sont utilisés dans tous les contextes en Belgique, tant familiers qu'officiels. Ils n'y sont pas considérés comme des mots de dialecte et sont d'ailleurs même utilisés dans les écoles de tous niveaux (j'ai fait mes études en Belgique, et je n'ai jamais entendu un professeur utiliser "quatre-vingt-dix" ou "soixante-dix", même les professeurs de français). Concernant les documents officiels, ils y sont également utilisés: je suis par exemple né en 1975, et les documents officiels belges qui mentionnent ma date de naissance en toutes lettres  mentionnent bien "septante-cinq".

Answer (score 6):

Ok, après quelques recherches, j'ai trouvé ceci:

http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#78_strong-em-septante-octante-nonante-em-strong

> Il est à noter pourtant que les mots septante, octante, nonante
>   figurent dans toutes les éditions du Dictionnaire de l’Académie
>   française. Encore conseillés par les Instructions officielles de 1945
>   pour faciliter l’apprentissage du calcul, ils restent connus dans
>   l’usage parlé de nombreuses régions de l’Est et du Midi de la France,
>   ainsi qu’en Acadie. Ils sont officiels en Belgique et en Suisse

Donc oui, ce sont bien des termes officiels

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what Robuste means by saying that septante, octante and nonante are official in Switzerland.  There is no national language academy in Switzerland (one of the reasons Switzerland was not involved in the proposed spelling reforms of 1990:  There was no official body with which to consult).  Indeed, in Switzerland, the accepted usage varies by area.  In Geneva:  septante, quatre-vingt, nonante; in the canton of Vaud:  septante, huitante (in some areas:  octante), nonante.

Comment: I wonder if you really took the time to investigate Robouste’s answer before commenting it. Robouste was citing a text from l’Académie française, which can be found if you follow the link provided in the answer. It has nothing to do with his/her opinion.

Comment: Mutatis mutandis, the point still stands.

Comment: @Feelew L'article de l'Ac. manque peut-être de nuance sur l'emploi selon les divers cantons, voir par exemple [ceci](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombres_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Suisse)... et la réponse est présentée de manière peut-être un peu maladroite comme un rejet de l'Ac. plutôt qu'une affirmation de la diversité des cantons etc. Merci !